# Calculate broadcast ip address using ipcalc

Tags: bash, ip

I have a list of ip addresses in cidr formart in a text file,one cidr per line and I would like to calculate the broadcast ip address of the cidr. I understand that I can do that using ipcalc with the -b option but ipcalc doesn't take a text file full of cidr. So, how to write a bash script to wrap around the ipcal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick script that should do the trick:

Example file ips.txt

```
$ cat ips.txt 
192.168.0.1/24
192.167.0.1/24
```

Example output for the ips in this file:

```
$ for i in $(cat ips.txt);do echo $i; ipcalc -b $i;done 
192.168.0.1/24
BROADCAST=192.168.0.255
192.167.0.1/24
BROADCAST=192.167.0.255
```

If you don't need to output the ip address itself, just remove the echo.

*Edit*

Here's a version that prints only the broadcast address, as requested:

```
$ for i in $(cat ips.txt);do bcaddr=$(ipcalc -b $i);echo ${bcaddr#BROADCAST=};done
192.168.0.255
192.167.0.255
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but i wish it could just print the broadcast ip address only on screen